# How do you Convert Sympy's "Mod()" to Python's Syntax of "%"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I was wondering how I would go about converting Sympy's "Mod()" to Python's default syntax of the percent sign (%). I cannot find any "built-in" function (in the Sympy package). I **could** write one myself, except I want the result to be simplified. In the function that I would create, I've realized that I don't know how to avoid adding extra parentheses. Since I want it in its most simplified form, I would need to use Sympy's simplification. And that would then undo the conversion of "Mod()" to "%". So if there isn't an easy way to convert Sympy's Mod to Python's "%", please tell me there's a way in Sympy to simplify only parentheses. I've looked, and I haven't been able to find that either. I at least want a way to remove redundant parentheses without converting "%" back to "Mod".

**Edit:**

Here's an example,  I want:

```
Mod(x + 1, 3)
```

to become:

```
(x+1)%3
```

But I don't want:

```
Mod(x, 3)
```

to be:

```
(x)%3
```

I want it to be:

```
x%3
```

Comment: to get rid of the brackets you can just check the arguments [precedence](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.precedence.precedence) but I'm quite surprised this doesn't already exist.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thank you, but I still don't know how that helps. Maybe you could explain how that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have done a bit of looking into sympy's options for custom printing it looks like it is quite easy to implement:

```
from sympy.printing.precedence import precedence
from sympy.printing.str import StrPrinter

class MyPrinter(StrPrinter):
    def _print_Mod(self,expr):
        own_level = precedence(expr)
        args = (self.parenthesize(arg, own_level) for arg in expr.args)
        return "{} % {}".format(*args)
```

The `printer`'s method `parenthesize` takes an expression and a "level" where the level represents the precedence threshold that causes it to actually add brackets around the argument, so it will only put parentheses around operations that need them:

```
from sympy.abc import x

printer = MyPrinter()
def test(expr):
    print(printer.doprint(expr))

>>> test(x%3)
x % 3
>>> test((x+1)%3)
(x + 1) % 3
```

From my **(extremely limited)** testing seems to suggest this works fine, also see the note below about `own_level`.

---

as shown in the [documentation for overriding printing](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.printer.Printer), you can just override `Basic.__str__` to use your custom printer when just printing out expressions:

```
from sympy import Basic

Basic.__str__ = lambda expr, printer=MyPrinter(): printer.doprint(expr)

>>> print(x%3)
x % 3
```

---

as a side note - the reason `Mod` doesn't / can't do this by default is because it apparently inherits from `Function`:

```
>>> issubclass(sympy.Mod, sympy.Function)
True
```

This is why it displays as a function call in pretty much every printing method there is, this also means that modulus has the same precedence as functions:

```
>>> precedence(x%3)
70
>>> f = sympy.Function("f")
>>> precedence(f(x))
70
>>> print( f(x)%x ) #so it thinks f(x) needs parens here
(f(x)) % x
```

if you find an appropriate precedence to use for `own_level` please share it with me as I would love to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is one slight problem with it, though. The second parameter is not surrounded with parentheses when needed (if an operation outside the portion that's being manipulated has a higher priority than modulus -- 'Mod('x',3)/3' becomes 'x%3/3' when it should become '(x%3)/3'). Though, I'm sure this won't be that difficult to fix. Other than that, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: hmm, actually I think it would be difficult to fix, for that to work it would have to identify that Mod has the same precedence as div which due to it's implementation as a function doesn't seem to be strait forward, sorry I can't help with that :(